# java change element type in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a code like this :

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s="null, arco, baleno";
     Object[] arr=s.split("\\,");
     for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
     {
         System.out.println(arr[i]);
     }
    }
}
```

I need possibility to change type of arr[0] or other elements from String to int or other types,how can I do that?

thanks in advance.
ciao h.

Comment: do you want to store the new data in the same array? or do you want to put it in a new array?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Java arrays store elements of single type.

That's unlike i.e. python lists where you can do

```
 l = ['a',2, 3.0]
```

In java you'll have to create a different array of the type you need and convert each element of your array accordingly i.e. by parsing it.

Answer (score 2):

try with this

```
Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
```

assign it to new integer array like

```
newArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
```

newArray is an integer array

Comment: The statement `Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);` would not work because the `parseInt()` method doesn't accept the `Object` type value like this `Integer.parseInt(Object);`. Note that the type of `arr[]` is `Object` that you're supplying as a parameter to `parseInt()` which would cause a compile-time error.

Comment: yes its right, we can convert object to string using toString() method, so can change above convertion like this newArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i].toString());

Answer (score 2):

You can change from string to int in different ways as follows.

```
Integer.parseInt(arr[i].toString());
Integer.valueOf(arr[i].toString()).intValue();
Integer temp=new Integer(arr[i].toString());
```

---

You can parse the elements of `arr[]` to `int` and store into another array as follows.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s="1,2,3";
        Object[] arr=s.split("\\,");
        int temp[]=new int[arr.length];

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            temp[i]=Integer.parseInt(arr[i].toString());
            System.out.println(temp[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can convert a data type to another data type as follows (using *auto-boxing* and *unboxing* techniques).

```
    Float f=new Float(arr[0].toString());
    f=Float.parseFloat(arr[0].toString());
    f=Float.valueOf(arr[0].toString()).floatValue();

    Double d=new Double(arr[0].toString());
    d=Double.parseDouble(arr[0].toString());
    d=Double.valueOf(arr[0].toString()).doubleValue();

    Long l=new Long(arr[0].toString());
    l=Long.parseLong(arr[0].toString());
    l=Long.valueOf(arr[0].toString()).longValue();

    Byte b=new Byte(arr[0].toString()).byteValue();
    b=Byte.parseByte(arr[0].toString());
    b=Byte.valueOf(arr[0].toString()).byteValue();

    Short sh=new Short(arr[0].toString());
    sh=Short.parseShort(arr[0].toString());
    sh=Short.valueOf(arr[0].toString()).shortValue();

    String str=String.valueOf(arr[0]).toString();

    Boolean bool=true;
    String boolStr=bool.toString();

    boolean boolPri=false;
    boolStr=String.valueOf(boolPri);
```